# Data with rare censoring

Tags: censoring

Scenario: Rats with condition and treatments. The response measurement is a gold standard measure of the condition. However, uncommonly, rats can die during the study. That means, technically, those rats are "censored", since the study goes on.

It is not a survival study, so survival isn't the outcome. However, time is a variable (time-course study). The response measurement is a count.

Optimal way to account for this rare "censorship"? In some runs, there are no animal deaths. In other runs, one or two animals may die out of 20+.

Comment: any reason to suspect that the treatments or conditions affect death rates?

Comment: Yes. the condition is associated with slightly higher mortality over a long term an the treatment may ameliorate the condition (with unknown effects on mortality).